# Adding Participant to locally hosted application (NetworkAdmin)

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm facing few issues with 0.16.0 version of composer while deploying the application on local network. Please help me to resolve it.

Steps Followed:

1. Start Fabric: ./startFabric.sh
2. Create Composer Profile: ./createComposerProfile.sh
3. Create Peer Admin Card: ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
4. Network Deployment: composer network deploy -a perishable-network.bna -A admin -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -S adminST

*Here I'm not able to add participant*

5. Add Participant: composer add participant add -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -d '{"$class":"org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin", "participantId":"Abhilash"}'

Error: Error trying to ping. Error: No business network has been specified for this connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is a lot simpler than what you've tried. Have a read of the docs here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/composer.network.deploy.html

```
composer network deploy -a perishables-network.bna -A admin -S -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f networkAdmin.card
```

Now that you've created the network admin card (.card file) - you can import it to get this into the user's wallet.

```
composer card import --file networkAdmin.card
```

Lastly, ping the network - the first time its used, the certificates are retrieved:

```
composer network ping -c admin@perishables-network
```

this 'first use' will populate the user's (ie admin user identity) wallet in the .composer card store.

You don't need your step 5.